# Word-usage: "[...] that has had/ had everything..."

Tags: grammar, word-usage, present-perfect, past-simple, sentence-usage

Could you guys see this sentence and say if I should use Present Perfect or Past Simple?

> Haven't you heard the story about a character that **has had** / **had** everything and still **hasn't been** / **wasn't** happy?

I think it is Past Simple, because it sounds odd using the Present Perfect tense. Although, I think I should use the present perfect tense because there no time expression either here in the sentence, nor in the context.

Furthermore, could you tell why it was used Simple Past or Present Perfect?

Comment: He had everything, and he still wasn't happy.

Comment: Could you explain me why it was used Simple past then?